# Dynamically code API user input using getJSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, dynamic, getjson

I am trying to use the Unsplash API to generate images using a user's input. So far I've been able to retrieve images when query= is hardcoded but I want the results to vary based on what the user types and submits into the query. Below I've hardcoded "dog" as the query input.

Here is my code so far:

```
var client_id = "fcbcd3e60e7f6615d0e5c64ab8e830d9695c4c30a74586e8d234f9835923ad75";

$("#fieldsubmit").click(function(){
  query = $("#query").val();
})

$.getJSON('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=dog&client_id=fcbcd3e60e7f6615d0e5c64ab8e830d9695c4c30a74586e8d234f9835923ad75', function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var imageList = data.results;
  $.each(imageList, function(i, val) {

    var image = val;
    var imageURL = val.urls.regular;
    var imageWidth = val.width;
    console.log(imageURL);

  $('.grid').append('<div class="image"><img src="'+ imageURL +'"</div>')

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Either put the JSON call in a function to be called in the callback of the click handler, or add it to the callback itself (like I've done below), and use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to embed the variables right into the string.

```
$("#fieldsubmit").click(function(){
  const query = $("#query").val();
  const endpoint = 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos';
  const page = 1;
  $.getJSON(`${endpoint}?page=${page}&query=${query}&client_id=${client_id}`, function(data) {
    // ...
   });
});
```